# Weird behavior with BigQuery and Go?

Tags: go, google-bigquery

So I am doing a pretty simple query:

```
SELECT client_id FROM clients
```

And loading the results in a struct:

```
type Client struct {
  ClientID string `json:"client_id"`
}
```

However ClientID is never assigned.

If I change things to:

```
SELECT client_id AS client FROM clients

type Client struct {
  Client string `json:"client"`
}
```

Client will be assigned.

Why?

Comment: have you tried "type Client struct {Client_ID string \`json:"client_id"\`}" instead of ""type Client struct {ClientID string \`json:"client_id"\`}""  ? i think the problem was in selecting client_id while field in struct is ClientID

Comment: Interesting, will try that now... I don't think this was the case though in MySQL.